# Streamlining what roles and users see

Tags: user-roles

Another question I may not be phrasing right because having a hard time finding an answer. I would like the following functionality for my site. If I am assigned the role of Administrator, I can see all the pages on the site, pretty basic, but if I fellow contributor has a different role, let's say, Baseball Editor, then the only pages I want them to "see" in the Page Dashboard are the pages they have the ability to edit, which in this case would be only the Baseball pages they are assigned. The would not be able to even view or see the Football pages, for example. Anyone know of a solution or point me in the right direction? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of options here. One, which I've found the easiest, is to move content you want to protect into custom post types. From there, you create specific permissions (capabilities) for each CPT, and WP will automatically only show the content that the current user has permission to edit in the back end.

The other option is to seek out a plugin. There are a few role plugins available which allow you to set permissions in various ways, such as selecting certain pages that each user or user group can edit. You're then dependent on the plugin, but it's easier to set up and get going that way and doesn't require any URL changes like CPTs may.